# Differentiating between sdl structure and sdl functions

Tags: sdl

Is there any way to differentiate between sdl structures and sdl functions,because their way of naming structure and function is quite similar and sometimes i end up declaring object for sdl function. 
For example,SDL_Window is a structure but SDL_Quit is a function.

Comment: Yes there is, `Quit` is a verb ( something you can do ) while `Window` is an object. I don't think there is a different way, but you can check out the documentation. Or, as the answer suggests, memorize it. There's not too many structures, you'll learn it as you get more experience with SDL. Documentation can be found here : http://wiki.libsdl.org/ Btw; if you use SDL2, you should add the SDL2 tag

Answer (score 1):

Intellisense tells you that, assuming you are using VS. Otherwise, no, none other than look them up in the documentation, or memorize it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio, Code::Blocks, or other IDEs, they have an auto-complete function that shows what types are available. If you're using a plain text editor, then, no, there is no differentiation; all SDL functions and objects start with "SDL_" to prevent naming conflicts, and that's it. But as stated above, looking at the difference between noun and verb will likely be all you need.